# WSO2 non-english characters in URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are working with WSO2 2.6. Currently our database has the latin1-swedish-ci default, but we can switch to utf-8 if necessary.

We are trying to work with non-english characters in the API context. Currently we took carefully only characters that are included in latin1 set of characters, e.g: /t/tenant.com/Process_educação/1.0.0 (those are Portuguese characters, part of latin1).

We were able to create such API in API Publisher, and were able to call it from Postman application. However, trying to call it from a Web browser failed with error 202(Accepted). That is because the Web browser "encodes" the URL to:

```
https://apigw-pod1.staging4.infaqa.com:8243/t/apim.stg4p1.com/Process_educa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/1.0.0
```

And WSO2 does not recognize this URL. In the log I only see the following:

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -
    To: local://axis2services/Process_educa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/1.0.0, 
    MessageID: urn:uuid:7c3cbd55-570f-4e66-97a6-34845fb1a1d6, Direction: request
```

I was also trying with the following URL:

```
https://apigw-pod1.staging4.infaqa.com:8243/t/apim.stg4p1.com/Process_educa%E7%E3o/1.0.0
```

As this is the correct latin1 representation of the characters, but got the same 202(Accepted) when invoking the API.

I noticed the following blog: https://medium.com/working-with-wso2-products/how-to-use-non-english-languages-with-wso2-api-manager-851a3124c436, which suggest working with UTF8 in WSO2 DB.

Questions

1. Is the blog correct and updated for WSO2 AM 2.6? Can we safely follow its suggestion and benefit /context with any UTF8 characters?
2. After we follow the suggestions of this blog, will WSO2 accept encoded URLS (with '%')? Or would we still have a problem that it only accepts non-encoded URLs (containing UTF8 characters) and reject their encoded representation?

Any further insights will be appreciated!